# Unable to capture Parameter value from AWS Parameter Store if executed from the Cypress Tests(Mocha blocks)

Tags: aws-parameter-store, getparameter

**Unable to capture Parameter value from the AWS Parameter Store**

I have tried doing it using aws-sdk, it worked when it's executed from the seperate node.js file, but when i tried the same from the mocha test(for cypress framework), then it's throwing an error as AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials is not a constructor.

I wanted it to work from the Cypress tests which are written using Mocha Framework (describe, beforEach and it block).

Note - I am trying it using javascript code.